# Accessing temporary file from upload in django view

Tags: ajax, django, file-upload

Just as the title says, I want to know how to access the data from the temporary file stored by Django, when a file is uploaded, inside a view.

I want to read the data uploaded values so I can make a progress bar. My methodology is to perform a jquery `getJSON` request:

```
function update_progress_info() {
        $progress.show();
        $.getJSON(progress_url, function(data, status){
            if (data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.uploaded) / parseInt(data.length);
                var width = $progress.find('.progress-container').width()
                var progress_width = width * progress;
                $progress.find('.progress-bar').width(progress_width);
                $progress.find('.progress-info').text('uploading ' + parseInt(progress*100) + '%');
            }
            window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, freq);
        });
    };
```

where `progress_url` is the view I have that handles the uploaded file data:

```
# views.py (I don't know what to do here):
def upload_progress(request):
    for line in UploadedFile.temporary_file_path
        response = (line)
    return response
```

Comment: Have a look at stringio and also this other post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949601/django-get-imagefield-path-before-saving-image/10950983#10950983

I asked a similar question before

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do... if it is a file uploader with progress bar, you can take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/).

Answer (score 6):

Django handles uploaded files with UploadHandler defined in `settings.py` with this name `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS` that defaults to this tuple:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = 
 ("django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
 "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",)
```

The behavior with file uploads is that if the file is less than 2.5 mg then it will be kept on memory, hence, they will not be written in disk as temporary files.

If the file weights more, it will be written in chunks in the `FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR` in the `settings.py`. That's the file you'll have to query to know how many bytes have been uploaded.

You can access the uploaded/uploading files through your `request` variables in `views` like this: `file = requests.FILES['file']` . There, `file` variable will have the type `UploadedFile` which contains a method `temporary_file_path` with the address of the file in the disk being uploaded. (*Note:* only files larger than 2.5 mg will have this methods) so there you may get the size of the file being uploaded.

Another way to do this is create your own `UploadHandler` like a `ProgressBarUploadHandler` and add it to your file upload handlers. This is the way the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers) recommend it. Here are some [snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/999/) and [tutorials](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/) for doing it.

If you need any more info the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) is really well documented.

I hope you find this helpful. Good luck.